# Join in pandas based on column interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, merge, interpolation

I'm trying to join 2 data frames based on the 2 columns. The problem is that I'd like to interpolate one of the column values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['ABC', 'USD', 2.31], ['DEF', 'MXN', 4.72], ['XYZ', 'EUR', 5.83]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>df1
    A    B     C
0  ABC  USD  2.31
1  DEF  MXN  4.72
2  XYZ  EUR  5.83

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['USD', 1, 0.5], ['USD', 2, 0.8], ['USD', 3, 1.5], ['MXN', 2, 0.6], ['MXN', 3, 0.71], ['MXN', 4, 0.88], ['EUR', 6, 0.12], ['EUR', 7, 0.5], ['EUR', 8, 0.7]], columns=['B', 'C', 'V'])
>>df2
     B  C     V
0  USD  1  0.50
1  USD  2  0.80
2  USD  3  1.50
3  MXN  2  0.60
4  MXN  3  0.71
5  MXN  4  0.88
6  EUR  6  0.12
7  EUR  7  0.50
8  EUR  8  0.70
```

I'd like to join the two data frames based on columns B and C such that I get the following result

```
     A    B     C      V
0  ABC  USD  2.31  1.017
1  DEF  MXN  4.72  0.880
2  XYZ  EUR  5.83  0.120
```

The interpolation is linear and uses the closest points when out of range.

The first value

```
1.017=0.8+(2.31-2)*(1.5-0.8)
```

The second value is there because the maximum value MXN has in df2 is 0.6

The third value is similarly the maximum value for EUR, which is 0.12

The goal is to do this as efficiently as possible since the dataframes are quite big.

As of now, I'm grouping by the B and using scipy interpolate function.

Comment: This is my current approach -
`ccy_dict = {ccy: interp1d(df['C'], df['V'], bounds_error=False,
             fill_value=(df['V'].iloc[0], df['V'].iloc[-1])) for ccy, df in ccy_df.groupby('B')}`
Followed by - 

`df1['V'] = df1.apply(lambda x: ccy_dict[x['B']](x['C']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with though I think you could probably improve this by using an apply with `scipy.interpolate` for the interpolation step. First create floor, ceiling and delta columns for df1.

```
enter df1['C_floor'] = df1.C.apply(np.floor)
df1['C_ceil'] = df1.C.apply(np.ceil)
df1['C_delta'] = df1.C - df1.C_floor
```

Do a double left join to obtain the `V` corresponding to the floor and ceiling of `C` from `df2`.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how ='left', left_on = ['B',  'C_floor'], right_on = ['B', 'C'])
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how ='left', left_on = ['B',  'C_ceil'], right_on = ['B', 'C'])
```

Here's where I think you could make the code faster, but I wrote a brief function to find the weighted mean and account for cases where `C` falls outside the range available in `df2`.

```
def weighted_mean(x):
    if np.isnan(x.V_x):
        return x.V_y
    elif np.isnan(x.V_y):
        return x.V_x
    else:
        return x.V_y + (x.V_x - x.V_y) * x.C_delta 

df1['V'] = df1[['V_x', 'V_y', 'C_delta']].apply(weighted_mean, axis = 1)
```

Finally some cleanup.

```
df1 = df1[['A', 'B', 'C_x', 'V']]
df1.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'V']
```

Which gives.

```
     A    B     C      V
0  ABC  USD  2.31  1.283
1  DEF  MXN  4.72  0.880
2  XYZ  EUR  5.83  0.120
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution! Works for me at this time. The only issue is that it won't work if the column **C** is a float as well.

Comment: If it is an evenly spaced float with a regular interval.g. 10.1, 10.2 etc. you can just multiply the column `C` by 10 (or any number), cast as an `int` and use the exact same code as long as you change the `ceil` and `floor` functions to round to the appropriate interval. What would be challenging and a different problem altogether, is if the intervals are not evenly spaced.